# mod rewrite and facebook - strip out extra URL info

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Slightly different mod rewrite question (I hope!) I've tried all the online tools and nothing does exactly what I want.

basically, I've got a URL:
http://mydomain.com/myfile.php?var1=0&var2=0&var3=2&var4=2&var5=0+num_posts%3D&fb_comment_id=fbc_10150188987337194_17133579_10150189957412194#f35528c832b7906

Everything after var5=0 (or whatever var 5 happens to be) is nonsense that I want stripped.

I would like it to say 'exactly'
http://mydomain.com/myfile.php?var1=0&var2=0&var3=2&var4=2&var5=0

which is basically:
"strip off everything after the var5=0 - so delete +num_posts-->onwards to the end.

obviously it would need to remember the variable values from the original URL - I only want to STRIP the +num_posts and onward.

Can someone help me with the correct mod-rewrite syntax for this?

Comment: I should add that this is due to facebook adding this stuff to the end of the URL when the comment link is clicked on FROM facebook. it goes to the correct URL, but since it has all the extra bits at the end, there are no comments on the landing page b/c it's technically a 'different' URL.

Comment: Do you know the order of the vars in the query and their exact format?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use **data-href** parameter in comments call? If you put explicit URL I think it must work as wanted. Look below code:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://mydomain.com/myfile.php?var1=0&var2=0&var3=2&var4=2&var5=0" data-width="470"></div>
```